# Intunes SDK integration for React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, intune

I have a react native application that runs on both IOS & Android devices. The organization has now mandated the integration of Intunes SDK into the application to apply Conditional Access & MAM policies. However the only integration available is a plugin which is 4 years old and the developer of the plugin has informed that he isn't maintaining it anymore.

https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/ms-intune-app-sdk-ios/issues/218

Is there a way to integrate Intune SDK into React Native application ?

-Rakesh

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your app is for internal use. easy way to integrate Intune SDK is using wrapper tool, don't need any code change. There are tool for both Android and iOS here is link iOS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-wrapper-prepare-ios

Comment: I suggest you to [edit] your answer to add the most part of the link in your post

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I had proposed the same to the internal digital support team however they rejected this solution and asked for the Intunes SDK integration to be done at an app level .

Comment: implement to React Native App is doable but it is not simple for android you may implement by Java and iOS by Object C.
Since this project is React Native I assume you not have to much experience on native mobile code.

you can take a look on this npm
https://github.com/Durgaprasad-Budhwani/react-native-ms-intune-mam
it help to integrate with MAM but for Conditional Access I not sure it will work

Comment: thanks a lot . Will try this out .